# Change ASCII to characters in string

Tags: python, python-3.x, ascii, python-3.6

i'm trying to convert ASCII values in string to normal characters, but whatever i'll try to do, i'll get output like

```
this\032is\032my\032\output\000
```

and I need

```
this is my output
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @RyanHaining Same as my output

Comment: In case you want to ask more questions on Stack Overflow: *what is your input?* and *what is your code?* Without these two, we cannot tell what you did wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it with

```
import re
def replace(match):
    return chr(int(match.group(1)))
aux = str(element.text)
regex = re.compile(r"\\(\d{1,3})")
new = regex.sub(replace, aux)
```

where `element.text` is string i need to convert

Answer (score 0):

`\032` is octal for the decimal number `26`, so it is not in fact a space character, if you use a hex value with the correct number, you should get what you want. `0x20 == 32` below

```
>>> s = 'this\x20is\x20my\x20\output\00'
>>> print(s)
this is my \output
```

Comment: I know, but I have to do it with decimal number

Comment: @Brykyz why? Are you getting numbers from user input that you are trying to convert?

Comment: Because it's school assignment

Comment: this is a very strange assignment if the strings actually have \032 in them since that already means something to python